# 55 Hour Long Single Epoch Colab GPU Training Time for a Small RoBERTa-like Transformer

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, corpus

I am following this guide: https://colab.research.google.com/github/huggingface/blog/blob/master/notebooks/01_how_to_train.ipynb

To train a transformer for Pali.  A dead language but has applicability for Buddhist texts.  I've got the Pali Cannon as training material (110+MB of text).  However, the training of a transformer on a single epoch with Colab takes 55 hours.  The transformer has 55m parameters.  This doesn't seem reasonable to me.  One of the problems that could be occurring is this is one piece of text.  I don't know if the model is interpreting each carriage return (\n) as new text, or if it's interpreting the whole of the Pali Canon as a single document.  Both of which I can see causing the rediculous training time.  From the tutorial, I gathered that <s> and <\s> mean the beginning of a document and end of document tokens in the corpora. However, I still don't know what keywords in the document set off the <s> markers. At first, I thought it might be \n but it looks like this doesn't set if off when using the OSCAR dataset the tutorial uses. I haven't integrated anything to denote end of document flags into my text of the Pali Canon. My question is right now the Pali Cannon text file is not formatted correctly for the transformer to train in optimal time so how should it be formatted so that it is correct?

Here is the link to the Pali Cannon text: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d1J1ib8LYnvapqY9FAWiMTHEA76XxC7b/view?usp=sharing

Here is the link to the folder containing the tokenizer files: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-2la-kfV_az0NdhCya5fPyleqTc4RJox?usp=sharing

Here is my code:

```
from transformers import RobertaTokenizerFast
from transformers import RobertaConfig
from transformers import RobertaForMaskedLM
from transformers import LineByLineTextDataset
from transformers import DataCollatorForLanguageModeling
from transformers import Trainer, TrainingArguments

import os


tokenizer = RobertaTokenizerFast("/content/drive/MyDrive/PaliBert/vocab.json","/content/drive/MyDrive/PaliBert/merges.txt", max_len=512)



config = RobertaConfig(
    vocab_size=52_000,
    max_position_embeddings=512,
    num_attention_heads=8,
    num_hidden_layers=2,
    type_vocab_size=1,
)


model = RobertaForMaskedLM(config=config)

dataset = LineByLineTextDataset(
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    file_path="/content/drive/MyDrive/Pali Cannon Analysis/Pali Cannon Text.txt",
    block_size=128,
)

data_collator = DataCollatorForLanguageModeling(
    tokenizer=tokenizer, mlm=True, mlm_probability=0.15
)



training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="./EsperBERTo",
    overwrite_output_dir=True,
    num_train_epochs=1,
    per_gpu_train_batch_size=64,
    save_steps=10_000,
    save_total_limit=2,
    prediction_loss_only=True,
)

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    data_collator=data_collator,
    train_dataset=dataset,
)

trainer.train()
```

Comment: Please try and restrict yourself to one problem at a time. FWIW, I can at least tell you that `LineByLineTextDataset` used in your example will chunk based on `\n` symbols, so this should (!) be alright.

Comment: Ahh maybe I wasn't clear there is only one problem I'm worried about.  The problem is that one epoch takes 55 hours to run.  All the other code is just necessary to reproduce this issue.  I think the <s> and <\s> are document endings (ie a given line), not spaces but I'm not sure.  But maybe I'm reading the hugging face tokens incorrectly.